# LINQ to Update View Count

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a **FormView** declared on the page

```
<asp:FormView ID="productDetail" runat="server" ItemType="products.Models.Product" 
    SelectMethod ="GetProduct" RenderOuterTable="false">...</asp:FormView>
```

The code behind it contains the following to display data in this FormView

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct(
                    [QueryString("ProductID")] int? productId,
                    [RouteData] string productName)
{
    var _db = new products.Models.ProductContext();
    IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
    if (productId.HasValue && productId > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.ProductID == productId);
    }
    return query;
}
```

So far so good.

Now I want to add a **UpdateViewCount()** method in the Page_Load which will increment a ViewCount field in the Products table **everytime the page is loaded**. How do I go about it? I have two challenges:

1. Extract Product Name from RouteData
2. Pass this productname to the UpdateViewCount which will look similar to the folllowing:

   ```
   public void UpdateViewCount(string prodname)
   {
    //   "UPDATE Products SET ViewCount = ViewCount + 1 WHERE ProductName = {0}", prodname);
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a route for default.aspx defined like that:

(url will look like http://yourdomain/Product/TestProductName)

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ProductsRoute", "Product/{productName}", "~/Default.aspx");
```

You can extract product name from RouteData like that:

```
var productName = RouteData.Values["productName"];
```

And then update your db like that:

```
using (var _db = new products.Models.ProductContext())
{
    var p = _db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductName == productName);
    if (p != null)
    {
        p.ViewCount = p.ViewCount + 1;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a very good solution. How do I handle scenarious where the same page is visited by more than one person at the same time? In that case, how will ViewCount increment?

Comment: In general this update is very fast, so SQL server will handle this for you. But if you know that there will be many simultaneous visits you can do some locking to sync the update operation: lock (lockObject) { using statement from above example here } where lockObject is just a private static object lockObject = new object();